# How to assign a value to a variable in extjs, which can be accessed globally over the entire extjs application

Tags: java, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am new to ExtJS. I designed a login page using ExtJS where a value is successfully returned from servlet response back to JS file as shown below.

LoginServlet.java

```
String user_role = "User1 - Admin";
myObj.addProperty("success", true);
myObj.addProperty("user_role", user_role);
out.println(myObj.toString());
out.close();
```

login.js

```
buttons: [{
                text: 'Login',
                handler: function(button)
                {
                    var formData = this.up('form').getForm();
                    formData.submit({
                        clientValidation: true,
                        url: '/LoginServlet',
                        method: 'POST',
                        success: function(form, action) {
                            user_role = Ext.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);
                            Ext.MessageBox.alert('User_Role', user_role.user_role);
                            window.location = 'userhome.jsp';
                        },
                        failure: function(form, action) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

Here in `Ext.MessageBox.alert('User_Role', user_role.user_role);`, i am getting a alert message as shown.

[image]

My need is to assign the value to a global variable so that I can access it in my entire ExtJS application (I have a common js file named header.js which is included in all JSP files in the application, I want to display the value of 'user_role' in header.js so that it will be displayed in all JSP files).

Note: I have defined 'user_role' variable as a global variable in a separate file globalVar.js (code below) and I have included globalVar.js as the first js file in all JSP files).

```
var user_role;
```

I am using ExtJS 4.2. Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Comment: You could store the user_role using LocalStorage (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.util.LocalStorage") or Cookies (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.util.Cookies).  Then wrap that functionality with a static class that stores/retrieves the value from there.  (http://extjsexamples.blogspot.com/2014/01/extjs-4-classes-statics-examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add a singleton class over your application in utility.

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.utilities.GlobalVar', {
      singleton : true,
      user_role : null
    }


    buttons: [{
                text: 'Login',
                handler: function(button)
                {
                    var formData = this.up('form').getForm();
                    formData.submit({
                        clientValidation: true,
                        url: '/LoginServlet',
                        method: 'POST',
                        success: function(form, action) {
                            user_role = Ext.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);
                            Ext.MessageBox.alert('User_Role', user_role.user_role);
                            **MyApp.utilities.GlobalVar.user_role = user_role.user_role;**
                            window.location = 'userhome.jsp';
                        },
                        failure: function(form, action) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

Assign global variable on success of form submit, and you can use the global variable anywhere in your application. [using MyApp.utilities.GlobalVar.user_role]

Answer (score 0):

It will be good if you use a store with storeId to keep the entire user data at one place.

Once you get response back from server. Update your Store with that value.

That store can be accesed from entire application.

Just do Ext. getStore('storeId') where store if is the id of store

it will keep your user data organises as well.